# What's another word for "enemy"

Tags: single-word-requests

Say you hate eggplant, but you're forced to eat it.

Eggplant is your ***_*____** (enemy?)

Comment: *Enemy* is not quite what you intend to say.

Comment: ...ultimate turnoff (still considered slang, and would sound unnatural in 'Eggplant is my ___' without the adjective) –

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus? Or even just a dictionary?

Comment: No one's mentioned adversary.

Answer (score 1):

Kryptonite. If you don't mind the pop culture reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to imply an it holds a special position as a source of antagonism, you could use [*nemesis*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nemesis). From the [OED](http://www.oed.com):

> a persistent tormentor; a long-standing rival, an arch-enemy.

If you want something less dramatic, how about [*pet hate*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pet+hate)?

Answer (score 0):

For emphasis you could use:

[bane](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bane) - "Eggplant is the bane of my existence"

[Nemesis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nemesis) - "Eggplant is my Nemesis"

Answer (score -1):

You could call it your *[bete noire](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bete+noire)*:-

> a person or thing especially disliked or dreaded; bane; bugbear.

although I think that would be a bit hyperbolic in the context you have given.

Answer (score -2):

You probably mean ***bitter pill to swallow***

But to avoid mixing metaphors I would suggest ***necessary evil***

Comment: I don't think either of those are suitable, really.  "Bitter pill to swallow" is a metaphor with a specific meaning (unpleasant news, unavoidable but deeply unpleasant fact). Ising that metaphor in an almost literal sense is neither good nor creative use of language and could even cause confusion.  "Necessary evil" is just wrong, since we know somebody is being forced to eat it but we have no reason to think that this is actually necessary or justified.

Comment: Not sure where you get your definitions from but you are entirely mistaken on both counts: Bitter pill to swallow (Cambridge dictionary) - something that is very unpleasant but must be accepted; is fully applicable in the context OP means.

Comment: Metaphors are meant to be creatively used, meaning in situations that are not necessarily literally applied.

Comment: But you're using it literally and not at all creatively.

Comment: OP was only giving an example to establish context. Moreover pill does not equate with eggplant and the metaphor cannot be considered literal in any literal sense.

Comment: The swallowing is literal.  You have reduced the metaphor to a simile (one unpleasant-tasting thing compared with another).  Once again, you are quite wrong (and very careless with the word "literal").

Comment: didn't think OP was averse to similes - not sure if you are now objecting to my answer from another frame of reference?

Comment: I'm objecting to clumsy use of language.  It overcomplicates to no purpose and very possibly creates confusion.  Even if we ignore the fact that this was a single word request, your suggestions are inelegant.

Comment: my answers are proving to be a bitter pill for you to swallow indeed.

Comment: Not at all, since I am under no obligation to accept them, nor will I (though I certainly consider them indigestible).  But this has gone on too long.